# Can "higher order function" feature allow/maintain abstraction and encapsulation?

Tags: python, functional-programming, abstraction, encapsulation

Below is the function `repeat` written using a functional paradigm, such that when called as `repeat(square, 2)(5)` it will apply the `square` function `2` times on the number `5`, something like `square(square(5))`.

```
def repeat(f, n):
    def identity(x):
        return x
    def apply_n_times(n):
        def recursive_apply(x):
            return apply_n_times(n - 1)(f(x))

        if n < 0:
            raise ValueError("Cannot apply a function %d times" % (n))
        elif n == 0:
            return identity 
        else:
            return recursive_apply
    return apply_n_times(n)

def square(x):
    return mul(x, x)
```

With regards to abstraction, I see that `repeat(square, 2)` returns an implementation detail in the form of `apply_n_times(n - 1)(f(x))` multiple times before providing the actual result.

With regards to encapsulation, for the expression `f = repeat(square, 2)` one could mutate the members of function object, for example:  `f.__name__='garbage'`

Does the concept of `higher order function` allow supporting abstraction and encapsulation? Because they return the implementation details and provide access for mutation.

Such existing implementations in large software are very tedious to use, as the user has to have an idea of the implementation before using it.

Answer (score 14):

> Wrt abstraction, I see that repeat(square, 2) returns implementation detail in the form of apply_n_times(n - 1)(f(x)) multiple times before providing the actual result.

The function returned by `repeat(square, 2)` is not an implementation detail; it's the whole point of calling `repeat`. An implementation detail is something that the caller doesn't need to know about (and in most cases isn't allowed to know anything about either) and that could be changed without breaking any of the caller's code. The caller wants and needs the function returned by `repeat`.

It seems to me that you're looking at `repeat` as if its purpose is to give you the result of applying `f`, and that's why you see the fact that it returns `apply_n_times` as an implementation detail. If you only wanted the result of composing `f` with itself `n` times, you could have defined `repeat` to take three arguments. But what makes curried functions useful it the fact that you can make use of the in-between functions it creates! E.g.

```
numbers = range(1, 10)
numbersSquaredTwice = map(repeat(square, 2), numbers)
```

In other words, their purpose isn't to compute the final result, it's to compute a function that can compute the final result. The function returned by `repeat` is a useful thing to have in and of itself.

> With regards to encapsulation, for expression f = repeat(square, 2) one could mutate the members of function object, for example: f.**name**='garbage'

Everything in Python has metadata that can be inspected and modified, and function objects are no exception. Python won't stop you from deeply inspecting and messing with every piece of data in the program. That lets you break almost any abstraction if you choose to do so. So you could say that it's Python that doesn't have very good support for encapsulation. In functional languages a function doesn't "know its name", because asking a function for its name makes about as much sense as asking an integer for its name. Functions don't need names, and if you choose to give them one, they don't need to know it.

But do note that every call to `repeat` produces a *new* function object, so even if you choose to muck around with it, the changes you made won't affect the return values of other calls to `repeat`.

Comment: For your point: `you can make use of the in-between functions`. Do you think the user of `repeat` has to know the implementation details of `repeat`, to make use of partially applied functions(PAF) returned by  `repeat(square,2)`? Having advantages of PAF is different aspect(`map(repeat(square, 2), numbers)`).

Comment: Problem is, As a python FP programming beginner, If I start practising function currying to resolve homework problems, Will I face issues at advance level in writing big software? As a Java OOP programming beginner, Java allows programming to return instance of a class that maintain abstraction/encapsulation.

Comment: @overexchange The caller doesn't need to know implementation details. It only needs to know about the return value. You're going to run into problems using Python for FP regardless; it doesn't have proper tail calls so you risk running out of stack, and its syntax for lambdas is verbose. I would argue that dynamic typing is not fit for big software either. I think you're looking at the wrong language for the kinds of programs you want to write. Something like Haskell or F# would be better suited to your needs.

Comment: @overexchange Python has acquired a few functional features but Guido is hostile to any attempt to make Python a functional language.  He doesn't believe that the functional paradigm suits Python.  Hence the lambda support being crippled.  If you want a scripting language with much better fp, consider Lua (Pythonistas often find it friendly).  If dynamic is your main thing, look at Erlang.  But Python will waste your time on this.

Comment: @itsbruce I don't think I can recommend Lua to him. While it does have proper tail calls, its lambdas are even more verbose than Python's (`function(x) ...`) and it makes other very dubious design choices: 1) indexes start at `1` instead of `0`; 2) accessing an undefined variable doesn't raise an error; 3) variables are global by default (you need to add the `local` keyword); 4) everything is a mutable table, and attempting to make them immutable requires some hackery. The standard library is also very small and there's a lot of wheel-reinventing; not exactly the stuff big software is made of.

Comment: Doval, what about webclint language JavaScript? Is it a good choice to do functional programming paradigm? Because I need to get into web dev world.frontendmasters teach hardcore functional programming using JavaScript.

Comment: @overexchange Sorry, but language/technology choice is a complicated affair, web technologies even more so. The comments section isn't really a place for lengthy discussion, and this is getting too long already. You'll have to do research and decide for yourself.

Answer (score 7):

The benefit of abstraction is that the caller doesn't **have** to know about implementation details. If I understand correctly, you're questioning this python construct because the caller **can** find about about implementation details. That's not the same thing.

*Not having to know* about how a method does its job is useful. It aids the software developer in their job, because you can think about *one* level of detail at a time instead of having to juggle two of them simultaneously.

*Being unable to find out* is something quite different. It can be useful to give the library programmer greater freedom for later optimization without anything breaking. But in practice, it suffices to simply declare in your API "Any intermediate types visible through the returned helper object are not part of the contract, and using them is undefined behaviour". That way the library writer retains the same amount of freedom, and only callers who willfully break the explicit contract suffer from it, while the main benefit (being able to ignore the details) stays unchanged.

Comment: If a caller makes an expression `repeat(square, 2)(5)`, caller definitely understands that a partially applied function is being returned after evaluating expression `repeat(square, 2)`. So, We are giving the liberty to break the expression as `f = repeat(square, 2)` and `f(5)`. Does the caller need to have an idea about implementation details before breaking this expression?

Comment: I'm not Pythonic enough to say for sure, but I'd have thought the fact that a function is returned is definitely part of the contract. Otherwise, how would you know that the return value supports the `()` operator? However, I'm more of a static typing person, so I view that more as a type declaration than an implementation detail.

Comment: My point is, `repeat(square, 2, 5)` would have happily maintained abstraction and encapsulation. But I think, here returned `int` type object with value  `625` can also be tampered to break encapsulation.

Comment: "But in practice, it suffices to simply declare in your API...": This really depends on the application. If you are programming a web application, then the worst that can happen is you get a `404` error or something similar. If you are writing mission-critical software, you want your abstractions to be as opaque as possible.

Comment: If someone is making mission-critical software *using* your code, it's *their* job to make appropriate non-fragile use of the APIs they're using. It's *your* job to clearly communicate what your clients can and cannot rely upon, and to make sure those properties you advertise as reliable really are bullet-proof.

Comment: @Ben: This does not change the fact that an API is more robust if it encapsulates its internal implementation and only exposes those advertised, bullet proof properties. As a person in charge of choosing a library for a mission-critical application I would opt for a more robust API instead of a fragile one which requires more work on my side to be used properly.

Answer (score 6):

The caller doesn't so much need to know the implementation details of `repeat(f, n)` as he needs to know its *return value*.  In this case, the return value is a little more complicated than most, because it returns a function.  In a static language like Haskell, this is easily documented in the function signature like:

```
repeat :: (a -> a) -> Int -> (a -> a)
```

This tells you it returns a function that takes an `a` and returns an `a`, but you don't need to know any implementation details of that function, just its signature and semantics.

The main weakness of dynamic languages like python is that their types, including their return types, are not documented in their function signatures (the main strength is the programmer isn't forced to document them).  This leaves you with either documenting return types in a comment/docstring, or reading the function body or contextual clues in the calling code to determine them.  You have always had to do this with *all* functions, not just higher-order ones.  You probably just didn't notice because your functions have generally been small or simple enough to not be problematic, and complex third-party code you have used has generally had good docstrings.

Python also has a grand tradition of information being hidden by convention, not by dictate of the language.  If you can't tell if something should be a private implementation detail or not, you need to document that as well.  I generally consider the body of any closure to be a private implementation detail, whether returned or not.